How does AC backfeeding work?
How/when does AC backfeeding work (such as in a grid-tied solar power generator plugged into a 120V wall socket)? Is a slightly higher voltage required to backfeed?

Yes, depending on ESR * I while locked in phase.

In order to feed a controlled amount of current, with decent power factor, into mains (which has very low impedance at low frequency), you basically need a series inductor. Look at a bridgeless PFC circuit, and turn into an H bridge, so you can apply the DC voltage to mains via the inductor.

Back-feeding to the grid is done by injecting a current (not a voltage). The grid-tied inverter generates a current that is proportional to the instantaneous grid voltage.

Is a slightly higher Qvoltage required to backfeed?

Indirectly, yes. But not because the grid-tied inverter generates a higher voltage. The higher voltage is just a consequence of the current that the inverter injects onto the grid and the grid's non-zero resistance.
There are a couple of challenges with back-feeding:

Dog chasing its tail. Positive feedback can result in an uncontrolled situation. The current is proportional to the voltage, which raises the grid voltage slightly due to its non-zero resistance, which in turn gets the inverter to feed more current.

Islanding. In case of a black-out, and the load includes a motor, the motor keeps on spinning, the inverter sees the motor voltage, and thinks it's the grid voltage, so it continues operating. The linemen come over to fix the power line, which they assume is dead, and instead get killed by the voltage from the inverter.


Both have solutions.
